# Stop atieventsd flooding my journalctl

Tags: logs, ati

When running `journalctl -f`, this line shows up every seconds..

```
Month DD HH:MM:SS computername atieventsd[number]: xauth:  file list does not exist
```

for example

```
May 15 08:32:11 gravity atieventsd[355]: xauth:  file list does not exist
May 15 08:32:12 gravity atieventsd[355]: xauth:  file list does not exist
May 15 08:32:13 gravity atieventsd[355]: xauth:  file list does not exist
```

What is this and how should I stop this? (I haven't found any hint on google)

Comment: Looks like the same issue here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/409815/fglrx-and-the-broken-atieventsd-daemon-maybe-improve-your-battery-life-for-amd

Comment: Can you confirm that you have `xauth` installed? `type -f xauth`.

Comment: yes, `xauth is /usr/bin/xauth`

Comment: These messages are related to your ATI video card's drivers. Do you have a card that uses these drivers?

Comment: yes, `Driver      "fglrx"` on xorg.conf, 
`dmesg | grep fglrx` at http://pastie.org/9178966 and `lspci | grep VGA`: `00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Richland [Radeon HD 8570D]`